# How do I use the DataContractJsonSerializer Class properly with powershell?

Tags: .net, json, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to take a json string in powershell 2.0 and convert it into a powershell object.

```
$json = '{"test":"data","numerical":4,"nested":{"nested":true}}'
$ms = New-object IO.MemoryStream (,$utf8.GetBytes($json))
[type] $type = 'psobject'
$js = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer $type
write-host $js.ReadObject($ms)
```

This produces nothing, no errors or output. How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work because the PSObject type does not have properties that match the JSON object.

One option is to create a .NET type or struct that matches the data to accept the conversion.

A second option is to [convert the JSON to XML using this](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/json-serializationdeserialization-in-powershell/) and then read the XML with PowerShell.

The third option I can think of is to convert directly to an object using [this project](http://powershelljson.codeplex.com/).

**[Edit]**

I also forgot about a script that Jaykul put together:  [JSON 1.7](http://poshcode.org/2930)

Comment: powershelljson doesn't seem to handle nested hashes or top level arrays

Comment: What about converting hashes?

Comment: These are just the options I can find.  You will have to choose the best or write your own.

Comment: Powershell 3.0 has this Nativity that works as expected one day I'll get to use that, for now Jaykul's script is the best of breed, and it falls down here and there.